# Find solutions of this equation

Tags: permutations, binomial-coefficients

If $a+b+c+d = 30$ and $a,b,c,d$ lie between $0$ and $9$. How to find number of solutions of this equation.

Comment: Are 0 and 9 inclusive??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the coefficient of $x^{30}$ in
$$
\left(\frac{x^{10}-1}{x-1}\right)^4
$$
Since
$$
(1-x)^{-4}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n+3}{3}x^n
$$
and
$$
\left(1-x^{10}\right)^4=\sum_{k=0}^4(-1)^k\binom{4}{k}x^{10k}
$$
we get the coefficient of $x^n$ to be
$$
\sum_{k=0}^4(-1)^k\binom{4}{k}\binom{n-10k+3}{n-10k}
$$
Note that $\binom{n-10k+3}{n-10k}=\binom{n-10k+3}{3}$ when $n\ge10k$.

Answer (score 0):

The answers are given here: [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%3Ca%3C9%2C+0%3Cb%3C9%2C+0%3Cc%3C9%2C+0%3Cd%3C9%2C+a%2Bb%2Bc%2Bd+%3D+30](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%3Ca%3C9,%200%3Cb%3C9,%200%3Cc%3C9,%200%3Cd%3C9,%20a%2bb%2bc%2bd%20=%2030)

However I do not know how these were calculated sorry.

Hopefully this will help give you a start to solving your problem.